# How can I show description for null column of a table in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model

I have column of a table that can contain null values, the datatype is of `string`. Now in the `Views` I need to show the data of that column, if the column contains the null then "No Details provided" show be printed otherwise the actual value of the data in that column. How to achieve this?

I have tried the following code:
MVC View Page:

```
@if (Model.Descriptions.summary==null)
{
   <span>No description has been provided by the owner.</span>
}
else
{
   @Html.Raw(Model.Descriptions.summary);
}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: your conditional check seems wrong. it should be `Model.Descriptions.summary==null`

Comment: sorry by mistake! actually its `==` only.

Comment: Add a `[DisplayFormat[NullDisplayText = ".....")]` to the property and use `DisplayFor()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank I got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the DataAnnotation attribute to the property in a model class like below,

```
[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText ="No Detail Provided")]
public string summary { get; set; }
```

otherwise used the ternary operator to check condition,

```
@(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.summary) ? "No Detail Provided" : item.summary)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @if (Model.Descriptions.summary==null)
{
   <span>No description has been provided by the owner.</span>
}
else
{
   @Html.Raw(Model.Descriptions.summary);
}
```

if above code is not working then replace **null with " "**, based on value what your returning if it is null check with null else check with " ".

Comment: yes, but that is issue as per his code, in my answer i have mentioned other way. please check text in my answer.